# Setting setHours zero not working in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

i am trying to get current date to compare and setting hours to zero but still getting time.

```js
    var today = new Date(new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0));
    var todaynew = today.toISOString();
    console.log(todaynew);
```

my output like :

```
2018-03-20T18:30:00.000Z
```

I need to get date as it is but time 2018-03-20T00:00:00.000Z

Comment: `toISOString()` returns time in UTC

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you create a `new Date()`, the time zone is that of the system. When you use `toISOString()`, the time is printed in UTC. This means that your code will print a different result when running on systems with different time zones (it prints `2018-03-20T23:00:00.000Z` for me).

Instead of using `setHours()`, use `setUTCHours()`.

```js
    var today = new Date(new Date().setUTCHours(0,0,0,0));
    var todaynew = today.toISOString();
    console.log(todaynew);
```